# How to calculate the integral $\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}} \, \mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

> For some $a$, $b$ in the domain of the integration of $f(x)=
>  \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}$, calculate $I$.
>
> $$I=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

But how do you find a primitive function for $\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$? It doesn't appear to be something that can be expressed in terms of a finite number of elementary functions.

Comment: Well, maybe you should try something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
We'll assume $\ds{0 < a < b}$:

> $$
> I=\int_{a}^{b}{\ln\pars{x} \over \root{x^{2} + 1}}\,\dd x
> =\int_{\theta_{a}}^{\theta_{b}}{\ln\pars{\sinh\pars{\theta}}}\,\dd\theta
> \quad\mbox{where}\quad\theta_{\mu} = {\rm arcsinh}\pars{\mu}\,,\quad \mu = a, b.
> $$

\begin{align}
\int\ln\pars{\sinh\pars{\theta}}
=
\half\left\{%
\text{Li}_2\left({\rm e}^{-2\theta}\right)
-\theta\left[\theta + 2 \ln\left(1 - {\rm e}^{-2\theta}\right)
-2\ln\left(\sinh\left(\theta\right)\right)\right]\right\}
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

Under the assumption that $x>0$,

$$ \begin{align} \int \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}} \, dx &= \int \ln (\sinh u) \, du \\ &=\int \ln\left( \frac{e^{u}-e^{-u}}{2} \right) \, du \\ &=\int \ln \left( \frac{e^{u} (1-e^{-2u})}{2} \right) \ du \\ &= \int \ln(e^{u})\, du +\int \ln(1-e^{-2u}) \, du- \ln 2 \int  \, du \\ &=\int u \, du -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\ln(1-w)}{w} \, dw -u \ln 2  \\ &= \frac{u^{2}}{2} + \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}(w)}{2} - u \ln 2 + C \tag{1}\\ &= \frac{u^{2}}{2} + \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2} (e^{-2u})}{2}- u \ln 2 +C \\& = \frac{\operatorname{arsinh}^{2}(x)}{2} + \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2} (e^{-2 \operatorname{arsinh} x})}{2}- \operatorname{arsinh}(x) \ln 2 + C \end{align} $$

$(1)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm

The antiderivative provided by Wolfram Alpha is valid over a larger domain, but apparently it simplifies to this result if $x$ is assumed to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the integrals fairly easily for most derivatives and integrals using WolframAlpha.

The equation that you would enter into Wolfram would look like this:

```
int(log(x)/sqrt(x^2+1))
```

Because of the computational complexity, Wolfram wants you to pay for the "pro" service, but you could just evaluate the output.  Here is a link to the [Wolfram Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRrgV.png)